# I am having problems in program of assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

This is the assembly program.

"Input Name and salaries of 3 employees and than add their salaries and display total salary and then display the average salary"

Here is the code

```
Msg_display Macro str
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset str
    int 21h
EndM Msg_display

.model small
.stack 100h
.data
        e1 db "Enter Name And Salary of 1st Employee","$"
        e2 db "Enter Name And Salary of 2nd Employee","$"
        e3 db "Enter Name And Salary of 3rd Employee","$"
    N1 db 20 dup(?)
    N2 db 20 dup(?)
    N3 db 20 dup(?)
    s1 db 0
    s2 db 0
    s3 db 0
        num db 0
        msg1 db "After Adding their Salaries, Result is....","$"
        msg2 db "Average Salary Is....","$"
        Ent db 0ah,0dh,"$"

.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

        Msg_display e1
    mov si,offset N1
    call input_str
    call No_input
    mov s1,ax

        Msg_display e2
    mov si,offset N2
    call input_str
    call No_input
    mov s2,ax

        Msg_display e3
    mov si,offset N3
    call input_str
    call No_input
    mov s3,ax

Input_str Proc
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    mov [si],al
    inc si
        cmp al,0dh
    JE end_input
    Jmp Input_str
End_input:
    mov [si],"$"
Input_str EndP

No_input Proc
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    cmp al,0dh
    JE skip

    sub al,48
    xor ah,ah
    mov num ,ax
    pop ax
    mul bx
    add ax,num
    push ax

skip:
    pop ax
    ret
No_Input endp

mov ax,s1
add s2,ax
add s2,s3

mov ah,09h
mov dx, offset msg1
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
mov al, s2
int 21h

mov ax,s2
mov bx,3

div bx
mov ah,09h
mov dx, offset msg2
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
mov dl,al
int 21h

mov ah,04ch
int 21h


End
```

I m keep getting this error "Invalid instruction operators at line # 32,38,44,66,69,77,78,79,86"

Comment: Which assembler? It is clearly for DOS, but the assembler matters

Comment: First of all, don't combine multiple different issues into one question. Ask separate questions.

Comment: Please also make it a habit to tell the potential readers/answerers which lines are number such and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
cmp [si],[di]
```

is an invalid instruction. It's invalid for several reasons:

1. `cmp` does not take 2 memory operands, very few instructions do and when they do, at most one of the memory operands is specified explicitly, the other is expected to be addressed in a predefined way implicitly without you telling it to the assembler.
2. the size of the memory operand(s) is ambiguous, the assembler cannot figure out if it should be a `byte`, a `word` or a `dword` (double word).

You should load one of the memory operands into a register and then do `cmp` with that register and with the other memory operand.

Btw, the lines like `mov [si],"$"` may also have problem 2 described above, because a number (which "$" resolves into, the ASCII code of "$") doesn't have a size associated with it and the memory operand is bare, lacking the size specification. The correct/unambiguous way is to spell out the memory operand size like this:

```
mov byte ptr [si],"$"
```

Macros aren't subroutines, you don't call them:

```
call Msg_display e1
```

This is invalid use of the macro. It should be something like `Msg_display e1` or `Msg_display(e1)` or `Msg_display<e>` instead.

There's no such form of the `div` instruction as here:

```
div ax,3
```

`div` takes one explicit operand (the divisor), and it's not an immediate constant (3). It can be a register or a memory operand. The other operand (the dividend) is either in `ax` (when doing 16/8=8,8 division) or in `dx:ax` (when doing 32/16=16,16 division). Also, remember to zero out `dx` if your dividend is 16-bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. problem related to macro is resolved and I used the actual way in which the div instruction work like I have to send dividend into ax and then divisor into bx and then just use the statement div bx and the resultant will store in ax. but the problem arises when I try to display it because the quotient is in ax and the thing that has to be displayed should be in dl register.

Comment: `mov` it digit by digit to `dl` and print those individual digits.

Comment: still there are lots of errors I edited my question. please check it

Comment: Questions that have been answered and whose answers have been accepted, aren't supposed to be morph into new questions. Revert the question and ask a new one.

Comment: I am not going to ask another question for the password program because our teacher said that you can compare whatever is at the address of si(source index) register and whatever present at di register. but you said that cmp instruction does not compare two operands, so I'll ask him about this problem. Thats why I removed that question. I liked your answer just because it solves my three errors but yet lots of errors are present there.

Comment: Either he was wrong, or you misheard/misinterpreted him. `cmp` cannot do that. There's `cmpsb`/`cmpsw`/`cmpsd` that can, but that's an entirely different kind of instruction and I didn't name it because I'd felt some extra explanation would be needed. See the instruction set in the CPU manual. All instructions and details are there.